# MySQL reference to field in another row

Tags: mysql

I want a MySQL field to be able to reference the same field in another row and return that field's value when loaded into PHP.

For instance, if row with `id = 1` has value `"bar"` in column `foo`, the row with `id = 3` should have value `"[1]"` (or something similar; the 1 is pointing to the row with `id = 1`) in column `foo` and MySQL should replace that value with `"bar"` when returning the array.

I'm not talking about an `UPDATE` query. I am trying to build a SELECT query that will make the appropriate replacement. I want `[1]` to be the permanent value of that row, and reflect whatever `foo` in the referenced row should happen to be.

Comment: You really need to read up about relational databases, set theory, and SQL syntax. Your question indicates very little knowledge of how a relational database operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this but without knowing more, your mileage may vary.

Also, simply use `1`, not `[1]` as the reference value

```
SELECT a.id, b.foo
FROM `foo_table` a
INNER JOIN `foo_table` b
    ON CAST(a.foo AS UNSIGNED) = b.id
WHERE a.id = 3 -- or whatever
```

### Update

I'd be more inclined to make your table design more specific. For example, try this structure

```
CREATE TABLE `foo_table` (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    foo VARCHAR(255),
    parent_id INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES `foo_table` (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Then your query can be

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.foo, a.foo) AS foo
FROM foo_table a
LEFT JOIN foo_table b
    ON a.parent_id IS NOT NULL
    AND a.parent_id = b.id;
```